# If $\lambda_{1,2}$ are complex conjugates then how to prove that $1 + \tau + \delta >0$ and $1 -\tau + \delta >0$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

Suppose $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2}$ are complex conjugates and also we have $|\lambda_{1}|<1, |\lambda_{2}|<1$.  $\tau = \lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2}$ and $\delta = \lambda_{1}\lambda_{2}$.

And in this case we also have $\tau^2 - 4\delta < 0$.

I am trying to show that $1 - \tau + \delta >  0$ and $1 + \tau + \delta > 0$

It is known that $\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{\tau \pm i \sqrt{4\delta - \tau^2}}{2}$.

From above, we have $|\lambda_{1}|^2 = |\lambda_{2}|^2 = \delta$

implying $0 < \delta < 1$.
Any ideas how to prove the inequalities $1 - \tau + \delta >0$ and $1 + \tau + \delta > 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll write $z$ for $\lambda_1$. We have
$$\tau = 2\Re(z),\qquad\delta=|z|^2 = \Re(z)^2 + \Im(z)^2.$$
it follows that
$$1-\tau+\delta = 1 -2\Re(z)+\Re(z)^2+\Im(z)^2 = (1-\Re(z))^2+\Im(z)^2>0.$$
Similarly,
$$1+\tau+\delta=(1+\Re(z))^2+\Im(z)^2>0.$$

Comment: Cool! I should have written more in my note!